# 3rd party libaries committed to svn: Better to check in many files or a zip?

Tags: svn

When committing third party libraries to source control, I've often done so as an archive with the unzip done as a build step. I guess the thought is that there can be thousands of files involved, and they're not expected to change, so it seems like a lot of overhead to store them all separately.

Unfortunately this approach sometimes brings headaches with it, including that when doing a full build a developer has to wait for the unzipping to occur. Sometimes dependency checks (to see whether unzipping is necessary) don't work reliably for whatever reason.

I can't find any mentions online of whether there are drawbacks to adding large numbers (in the case of one library I'm currently upgrading, tens of thousands) of files to a Subversion repository. Aside from taking up more space (over 1 GB, versus less than 250 MB), are there any reasons people know of that I should hesitate to commit a whole library as separate files?

Comment: I'd suggest mentioning 3rd party or library in the title

Comment: One reason to hesitate would be if there is any chance you'll ever need to apply a patch to the 3rd party source code.  If you do that and the 3rd-party-source is checked in as individual files, the change will show up clearly in "svn diff" output, etc.  If you change the file and check in a new .zip, on the other hand, SVN will show that the .zip was changed, but it won't be very easy to see what inside the .zip was changed.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a reason to hesitate to do the opposite (i.e. commit it as a zip)? Anyway, this was definitely one benefit I'd considered, and I'm certainly leaning toward doing this as separate files. (Really, the main reason to do the zip way here seems to be "well that's what we've always done"...)

Answer (score 2):

Is this Java or C or what type of development?

Either way, you can use [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/products.php) for storing third party libraries instead of source control. If it's Java, use Maven or Ant with Ivy. If it's C or C++, use wget or curl to fetch the third party libraries in your Makefiles. To store them, you can use Maven's deploy:deploy-file to put them into the repository. Or, if you use Jenkins, you can use Jenkin's built in ability to talk to a Maven repository to do the deed for you.

This has several advantages:

- You track your version numbering much better. When third party libraries are checked into the repository, people forget what version that was. For example, you check in `foo.so` version 1.2 into your repository. After a year, you don't remember which version it was. Others decide to check in a new version of `foo.so`. Again, you start to lose exactly what you have. Since this is a compile dependency, you need to know.
- Even if these are self generated third party dependencies, (You have a project that builds `foo.so` that's used in other projects), it's better to store them in a release repository like Artifactory. Again, you track versioning.
- It is easy to remove obsolete third party dependencies. In Subversion, the dependency is still kept in the repository even if you do a `svn rm` on the file. Save's a lot of diskspace.
- You don't have to worry about dependency bloat where obsolete third party files are kept in the build because you don't know if they're needed or not. Since you have to specify each and every dependency, it's easier for developers to track.

Comment: It's C++. We do try to include the version numbers in zip files that we commit, and I'd do the same for the directory if I commit all the files. And (it's a lousy reason, I know), but all other 3rd party libs we use are checked in, so it would probably be bucking the trend too much for me to make one of these alternative solutions! Your points are well taken though.

Comment: @Owen unless the files change by batch (That is, you put in one set of 3rd party libraries and then a new set after that), you're better off doing them one at a time. That way, each gets its own history. The only reason you'd want to do this in case you redo all 100 3rd party libraries at once. Then, you'll end up with a really long svn log every time you do a change. That's if you don't want to use a separate release repo for this.